# how to view where a thread is in code java

Tags: java, debugging

Can you print out what line in the code and what method a running thread is in, from within a program - without using some monitoring software like visualvm? Do you have to extend Thread?

Comment: *"how to view where a thread is in code.."*  **Why** to view where a thread is in code (with the arbitrary constraints)?  What program feature does this support?

Comment: if a thread gets stuck in a network call and there are many different network calls, its helpful to know which one

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is there a specific issue that you are trying to deal with, or is this just a more general question out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a call to [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29).  It returns an array of `StackTraceElement`, which represents the current StackTrace.  It will be helpful to remember that the top couple elements are going to be methods in `Thread`, so the ones that you are likely interested in will be down the array a bit.

Of course you need to get a hold of the `Thread` that is currently running...

```
Thread.getCurrentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Comment: the stackTraceElement will be at position [1] not [0].

Answer (score 3):

If this is just for quick-and-dirty debugging or error reporting, you can just do

```
new Exception().printStackTrace()
```

If you want to be a little fancier than that, you can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to get an array of `StackTraceElement` objects; you can determine the current line number by examining those.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Thread.dumpStack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack%28%29), which prints out the stack (similar to when an exception is uncaught). There's no need to create a new exception.

Answer (score 2):

Using just about any logging framework, most support Thread Group/Name, Class, Method, Filename and line number capabilities

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [JDB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html). [This link](http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2011/05/jdb-debugging-concurrency-issues-in.html) shows an example of using it to debug concurrency issues. [This](http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2011/04/jdb-command-line-debugger-for-java.html) also just shows some of its basic functionality. Its pretty decent and I believe it should already be in your JAVA_HOME/bin.

Another alternative is to check out the [JUCProfiler](http://www.infoq.com/articles/jucprofiler), I havn't tried this one, but it seems pretty decent.